# MS excel macro auto count function

Tags: vba, excel-2013, countif

Good day to all, currently I'm still facing problem of my boss task, to create a MS excel macro.

Problem facing now is

- auto count outdated data and show in the message box when user open worksheet.

I had tried so many code from internet sources, but the result still the same, it not able to run the code or the counted amount was 0.

Any one have any suggestion or solution. Thank you.

Below are 2 error codding

- This codding will only display 0 amount of outdated data.

  > > > CountedAmount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("L4:L1048576"), "Red")
- This codding will not running, warning show up Run-time error 1004 Application-defined or object-defined eror

  > > > CountedAmount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("L4:xlUp"), "Red")

These are the complete codding on my macro.

```
Sub Worksheet_Activate()

Dim CountedAmount As Integer

With Worksheets("Sheet1")

lastrow = Range("L1048576").End(xlUp).Row

'This codding will only display 0 amount of outdated data.
CountedAmount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("L4:L1048576"),     "Red")

'This codding will not running, warning show up Run-time error 1004  Application-defined or object-defined eror
'CountedAmount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("L4:xlUp"), "Red")

For i = 4 To lastrow

If Range("L" & i).Value <> "" And Now <> "" Then

    If Range("L" & i).Value <= Now Then
        MsgBox CountedAmount & " expiring"          
        Range("L" & i).Font.ColorIndex = 3

    End If
End If
Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This one works fine if the Value of the Cell is "Red" Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("L4:L1048576"), "Red") but if you want to count the amount of cells colored red, then you have to find something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to count the amount of cells colored red, then use something like this:

```
Dim startCell As Integer, endCell As Integer
Dim column As Integer
Dim CountCells As Integer

startCell = 4
endCell = 100

column = 12 'Column L

CountCells = 0

Dim i As Integer

For i = startCell To endCell Step 1

    If Cells(i, column).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then

        CountCells = CountCells + 1
    End If
Next i
```

Adjust startCell and endCell to match your Cell and column to your column. This loop currently searches from L4 To L100

And you have to find out which colorindex the red you are using has. You maybe have to use .Color instead of .ColorIndex, which uses an RGB Code.

Comment: thx for reply, but added in the codding ur provided into mine codding part, it not working, he count is still 0, due to the comment box had limited characters space, can i message with? by the way I dun know how to start message to a user, I'm new here..z

Comment: please tell me how the outdated cells are marked, if you just copied this code over, the colorindex might be wrong. If they are colored, tell me the Color or Colorindex (Click on the Cell and use Debug.Print ActiveCell.Interior.Color / ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex to see the value in the Debug WIndow)

Comment: >>>Font.ColorIndex = 3 yeah, it same with my previous codding. Based on the codding i posted, the outdated is  Due Date of contract compare with Today date, so if the Due Date => Today consider outdated, then the front color will change to Red color.

Comment: how about I edit the code u post to mine, then u able to check is that I placed wrong or something? Is that ok?

Comment: Yes, that would be an option

Comment: sorry fot the late reply due to the past weekend no having work. I had already edited your suggestion codding combined with mine, please have a look.

Why is that the expired employees contract cannot be count remain 0 when the message box pop up.